# UINavigationBarButtonItem not displaying text from Image

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I am using a PDF image for a `UINavigationBarButtonItem`, but the text from the image is not displaying on the button, and I do not know why. Do I need to use and SVG image format?

```
let liveIcon = UIImage(named: "LiveIcon")?.scaleTo(CGSize(width: 30, height: 20))
        liveStreamButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: liveIcon, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.liveStreamTapped))
        liveStreamButtonItem.tintColor = .systemRed
        liveStreamButtonItem.isEnabled = false
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [searchBarButtonItem, liveStreamButtonItem]
```

[image: Button appearance]
[image]

Comment: Try making `LIVE` cut a hole in the red circle (for transparency) instead of overlaying it as white text.

Comment: Can this layout work on a `UIButton`? If so, then try creating that first then use `UIBarButtonItem(customView:)`.